# move_node.jstree - finding/understanding operation result parameters

Tags: parameters, move, jstree

I'm using `jsTree 1.0-rc3`. I'm trying to find the operation result parameters, such as new position parent, new position order (index of the element among all children of a given parent), etc. I've managed to find out that:

- `data.rslt.op.attr("id")` = old parent id
- `data.rslt.np.attr("id")` = new parent id

but don't know about the rest. jstree is missing documentation here, I've spent several hours with it and I've run out of ideas. Btw, can anyone please decode the result abbreviations, these are:

- `cop`
- `cp`
- `cr`
- `np` - new parent
- `o`
- `op` - old parent
- `or`
- `ot`
- `p`
- `r`
- `rt`

I like jstree, but this naming convention drives me crazy.

Comment: I've asked Ivan (jsTree author) to comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

I know what is o.
o - stands for obj. When moving (dragging) a node, the moved object is in o.

You can access that obj using

```
data.rslt.o.attr("id");
```

Where as to access objects on which click event was triggered you got to use

```
data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually in the jstree core documentation. Right at the bottom of

```
 http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core.html
```

where it is mentioned while ._get_move() is being described!

Answer (score 0):

.o - the node being moved

.r - the reference node in the move

.ot - the origin tree instance

.rt - the reference tree instance

.p - the position to move to (may be a string - "last", "first", etc)

.cp - the calculated position to move to (always a number)

.np - the new parent